# Making a useEffect cleanup for multiple axios calls in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, axios, use-effect

I am trying to make an axios call to a video game database with a URL specific to the chosen option by the user. Depending on the 'opt' chosen, it will get all the data linked to the option and place into a useState ('selectedResults') as shown below

```js
function ViewContent() {
    const [selectedOpt, setSelectedOpt] = useState('none');
    const opts = ["Games", "Publishers and Developers", "Reviews", "Platform"];

    const [selectedResults, setSelectedResults] = useState([]);

    const getGames = (selectedOpt) => {

        if(selectedOpt == 'Games'){
            axios.get(apiURL.games)
            .then(function (response){
                results = JSON.stringify(response.data.data);
                setSelectedResults(response.data.data);
            })
            .catch(function (error){
                alert(error.message)
                console.log('getGameTest', error);
            })
            
        }
        else if(selectedOpt == 'Publishers and Developers'){
            axios.get(apiURL.creators)
            .then(function (response){
                // results = JSON.stringify(response.data.data);
                setSelectedResults(response.data.data);
            })
            .catch(function (error){
                alert(error.message)
                console.log('getCreatorTest', error);
            })
        }
        else if(selectedOpt == 'Reviews'){

        }
    };
}
```

The error I get is

`Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.`

Is there a way I can use the useEffect cleanup for multiple axios calls or would I have to make one for each? I am trying to look over some examples but I am not getting any progress. If I missed anything, feel free to ask and I will update the question.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to update react state when the component
is mounted.

```
export const useIsMounted = (): { readonly current: boolean } => {
  const isMountedRef = React.useRef(false);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    isMountedRef.current = true;
    return () => {
      isMountedRef.current = false;
    };
  }, []);

  return isMountedRef;
};
```

You can create a hook just like the above one or you can prefer useIsMounted hook from this [source](https://usehooks-ts.com/react-hook/use-is-mounted) in order to detect if the component is mounted. Then in your case, simply do the logic below.

```
if(isMounted.current) {
   yourSetStateAction()
}
```